# Traversing CRTP inheritance chain for template base classes with non-type template parameters

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

This is a follow up to the question:
[Get deepest class in CRTP inheritance chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533399/get-deepest-class-in-crtp-inheritance-chain)

The following code finds the first template argument which derives from the given instantiation of template CRTP base class and possibly recurses (this is just a more general solution to the previous question):

```
// Find the first type that matches the predicate
template <template <class T> class Predicate, class... Args>
struct FindFirstMatching {
    using Type = ...; // Default NullType
    static const bool has_match = ...; // whether there has been a match
};

// Utility class to get the deepest class in CRTP inheritance chain
template <typename T>
struct GetDeepest {
    using Type = T;
};

template <template <class...> class DT, class... T>
struct GetDeepest<DT<T...>> {
    template <class CLS>
    struct Predicate {
        static const bool value = std::is_base_of_v<DT<T...>, CLS>;
    };

    static const bool HasCRTPDerived = FindFirstMatching<Predicate, T...>::has_match;
    using DerivedT = typename FindFirstMatching<Predicate, T...>::Type;

    using Type = std::conditional_t<HasCRTPDerived, 
                                    typename GetDeepest<DerivedT>::Type, 
                                    DT<T...>>;
};
```

So I suppose that `DT<T...>` is in instantiation of CRTP base class. The problem is, it may have non-type template parameters as well, and I don't know how to cope with it in the most general way.

For example:

```
template <class DerivedT, bool param>
class ParamBase {
};

class Derived : public ParamBase<Derived, false> {
};

GetDeepest<ParamBase<Derived, false>>::Type == ParamBase<Derived, false>
// instead of desirable
// GetDeepest<ParamBase<Derived, false>>::Type == Derived
```

One of the possible solutions is to use something like type tags instead of non-type template parameters:

```
template <class T>
A {};

A<TrueType>;
A<FalseType>;
```

instead of

```
template <bool param>
A{};
```

But I believe it is not a good solution.

Also I could use something like `template <class..., auto...> DT`, but that would force me to use non-type template parameters in the end of parameter list. It is acceptable, but the problem is that it will fail disastrously if I forget about it.

It would be ok if I could write something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct GetDeepest {
    static_assert(!IsTemplateInstantiation<T>::value);
    using Type = T;
};
```

My question is:

How can I generalize the code to possible non-type template parameters?

OR

How can I implement `IsTemplateInstantiantion`?

Edit:
it seems like one cannot write `template <class..., auto...>` in C++17, so the latter is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I would go back to the first solution you proposed in your original question (the one that assumes that each non-leaf class template declares a `DerivedT` type that aliases its derived class). Let's recall your first implementation:

```
template <class T>
struct GetDeepest {
    template <class Test, class = typename Test::DerivedT>
    static std::true_type Helper(const Test&);
    static std::false_type Helper(...);

    using HelperType = decltype(Helper(std::declval<T>()));
    using Type = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<std::true_type, HelperType>,
                    GetDeepest<typename T::DerivedT>::Type,
                    T>;
};
```

You seem to be missing that leaf classes also inherit the `DerivedT` member type declaration from their base class. Which means that calling `Helper(std::declval<D>())` will call the overload that returns `std::true_type`. In other words:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    using DerivedT = T;
};

struct D : A<D> {
    using DerivedT = D; // inherited from A<D>
};
```

As a result, when instantiating `GetDeepest<D>`, `GetDeepest<D>::Type` ends up aliasing `GetDeepest<D::DerivedT>::Type` which is `GetDeepest<D>::Type` and the compiler complains about `GetDeepest<D>::Type` not being a complete type since it is trying to be an alias to itself!

Therefore, we need to change our recursion stopping condition. One solution that comes into mind is:

> A type `T` is a leaf-node in the CRTP hierarchy iff its `DerivedT` member type is an alias to `T`

And the implementation is pretty straightforward:

```
#include <type_traits>

// a type T is a leaf-node in the CRTP hierarchy iff:
// its DerivedT member type is an alias to T
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_leaf_type_v = std::is_same_v<T, typename T::DerivedT>;

// general case:
// GetDeepest<T>::Type is an alias to GetDeepest<T::DerivedT>::Type
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct GetDeepest {
    using Type = typename GetDeepest<typename T::DerivedT>::Type;
};

// base case: when T is a leaf type
// We have reached a leaf node => GetDeepest<T>::Type is an alias to T
template <typename T>
struct GetDeepest<T, std::enable_if_t<is_leaf_type<T> > > {
    using Type = T;
};

// tests
template <class T>
struct A {
    using DerivedT = T;
};

template <class T>
struct B : public A<B<T> > {
    using DerivedT = T;
};

struct C : B<C> {
};

struct D : A<D> {
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<GetDeepest<A<D> >::Type, D>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same<GetDeepest<B<C> >::Type, C>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same<GetDeepest<A<B<C> > >::Type, C>::value);
}
```

This approach does not require you to state the template arguments to your class in `GetDeepest` (which is the main issue in your 2nd questions If I understand correctly). I think that you can also implement `FindFirstMathing` in a similar manner.

I would also stay away from depending on `IsTemplateInstantiation` to query whether a type is a leaf-type in the CRTP hierarchy or not (even if it is possible to implement). One counter-example that comes into mind is `Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 3>` which is a class template CRTP leaf-type that inherits from `Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 3>>`. Such a distinction between classes and class template instantiations is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why my original implementation didn't work! Sometimes the error messages can be too confusing. 

For now I decided to replace non-type template parameters with type ones, and stick to the implementation described it the question body.

Both your solution and this one have a major flaw: if your forget a) `using DerivedT = ...` b) not to use non-type template parameters, then you're doomed to debug some cryptic runtime errors, in my case it has even caused UB. But I believe that a) is easier to miss.

I would like to know if there is a solution without such flaw.

Comment: "I would also stay away from depending on `IsTemplateInstantiation`"

I didn't intend to. It is just a safety mechanism: if one could have variadic both type and non-type in the same place, e.g `template <template <class..., auto...> class DT, class... T, auto... params>
struct GetDeepest<DT<T..., params...>>`, then the example with `ParamBase<Derived, false>` would give a good answer, we just need to ensure using `IsTemplateInstantiation` that the order type--non-type hasn't been messed up

Comment: Well @NikitaPetrenko, I don't think there is any solution to forgetting to add this member type alias (you have to check that yourself periodically). In the end of the day, you need to have something to distinguish leaf-node types from other types up the hierarchy. Personally, I would choose adding a type alias like `DerivedT` (see for example the design of the standard library iterators, which is a bit similar in my opinion). Relying on "A type is a leaf-type iff it is an instantiation of a class template" is not always true (as I mentioned in my answer).

Comment: If you choose to go that way, you lose both non-type template parameters (unless there is a solution that I can't see) and template leaf-types (like `Eigen::Matrix`). For these reasons, I find the member type alias solution to be much more flexible.

Comment: No, I don't miss template leaf-types by using this solution. E.g., line 157 from here demonstrates my usage
https://github.com/npetrenko/curse_dim/blob/fc60f8cf220aa3f7ee03addb079bd6d2e68fe427/src/kernel.hpp

Comment: @NikitaPetrenko, hmm, I see, you are relying on `std::is_base_of` to filter out template parameters that are not derived classes. Looks good to me. I believe you can also wrap your non-type template arguments in an `std::integral_constant` to overcome the non-type template argument issue

Comment: and now I am starting to think that your template template parameter approach in `GetDeepest` might be more flexible :)

Comment: @NikitaPetrenko, btw, is there any advantage to making `B<T>` inherit from `A<B<T>>` instead of simply inheriting from `A<T>`? In this case, You can get rid of `GetDeepest` altogether.

Comment: There are two advantages that I can come up with: 1) it allows `B<T>` to override methods from `A<B<T>>` 2) when inheriting from `B<T>` you only need to declare `friend class B<T>`, otherwise you also need `friend class A<T>`

Comment: @NikitaPetrenko, 1) I don't think I understand your point as you can [always override the methods wherever you like](https://wandbox.org/permlink/e4gWCAfut4Oa93uk) 2) Well, [proper encapsulation has always been a pain when using CRTP](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/296).

Comment: 1) -- yes, you are right. I use CRTP to implement a pattern which is different from usual virtual finctions: https://pastebin.com/EwSeT8s5. Technically speaking, I could refactor my code not to use it, but I find it more readable this way

Comment: hmm, I get your point, the base class is responsible to call the hiding function from the derived class. I haven't seen something like this before :) , but be careful not to forget to provide a hiding function in the derived when needed (or you'll get infinite recursion) :)